# How to add an application to startup using builder and stub

Tags: vb.net

I want an application to be added to the startup registry of windows...
This is very hard to code:
You have to load an .exe in a "builder".
The builder needs to load the stub etc, and you will get a new application as output?
I dont get it.

Does someone has experience with this and maybe has a simple example?

I have tried:

```
Try 
    Dim regkey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey 
    Dim keyname As Object = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" 
    Dim valuename As String = "RegName" 
    Dim value As String = filepath.Text '"RegistryDescription" 
    regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyname, True) 
    regkey.SetValue(valuename, value, RegistryValueKind.String) 
Catch ex As Exception 
End Try
```

Comment: It's actually not hard to code at all. Have you attempted it yet, or are you just hoping someone will post some code so you can copy-paste?

Comment: Yes i tried to make it. Maybe you mean something else... Its not on the application itself, like this: `Try
    Dim regkey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
    Dim keyname As Object = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
    Dim valuename As String = "RegName"
    Dim value As String = filepath.Text '"RegistryDescription"
    regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyname, True)
    regkey.SetValue(valuename, value, RegistryValueKind.String)
    Catch ex As Exception
End Try`

Comment: In that case, your question is entirely unclear. At least for me, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I have no idea what's being asked either!  What have you tried??  The code you posted should write an entry to the registry.. have you looked at the key to see what's been written??

Comment: I'm not sure about the problem you're having. Take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21cnPy5Pejo), I hope it will clarify a few things.

Comment: I think the answer is good enough